# Euler bricks and the $4^{th}$ dimension

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I've heard of Euler bricks, which go like this:

A [Euler brick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick) is a brick that has 3 sides, and any combination of the sides using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) will get a whole number. the Pythagorean theorem is:

$$
A^2+B^2=C^2
\text{  or  }
\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=C$$

I am wondering... is there any 4D Euler brick? as in A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, where

$$
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=e^2\\
a^2+c^2&=f^2\\
a^2+d^2&=g^2\\
b^2+c^2&=h^2\\
b^2+d^2&=i^2\\
c^2+d^2&=j^2\\
\end{align}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also, this may take a lot of computation, maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of $4$-dimensional Euler bricks is still an open problem. For the same question see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256122/euler-bricks-in-high-dimensions).

Comment: The definition in the linked question refers to a perfect cuboid, even though it then uses the term Euler brick. Either way, both are open problems in 4D.